# What is wrong with following reasoning?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ for $x\geq0$. After checking the convexity I can tell that $f(x)$ is convex for $x>c_1$ where $c_1$ is some positive constant. Now if I replace $x$ by $x+c_1+.001$ in my original function then is it ok to say that $f(x+c_1+.001)$ is always a convex function of $x$? I will be very thankful to you for your comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $x$ is still positive sure. But it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @VsevolodA. $x$ will still be positive. But why do you say that it does not make much sense?

Comment: @VsevolodA. do you mean my reasoning does not make much sense?

Comment: Maybe you somehow want to prove that $f(x)$ is convex for all $x$? Not just for $x>c1+0.001$?

Comment: @VsevolodA. Actually in this particular function I think it is impossible to show that it is convex for all $x\geq 0$. But after checking that the function is convex for $x>c_1$ I realized that in my particular problem the $x$ can not have a value smaller than $c_1$ therefore I can say that it is a convex function of $x$. Your thoughts?

Comment: That doesn't change much, since you still have it convex for $x>c_{1}$ but you want it convex for $x \geq c_{1}$.

Comment: @VsevolodA. I am sorry but I do not understand why you put equality in the sign $x\geq c_1$ while I mentioned in my post and comments that $f(x+c_1+.001)$ which I think implies that $x>c_1$? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: If there is no need for $\geq$ sign then the issue is as simple as one interval lying in another.

Comment: @VsevolodA. I am sorry but you might have noticed that I do not have much knowledge. So can you say that my reasoning is right? I will be very thankful to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I said that it's right in the first comment.

Comment: @VsevolodA. Thank you so much Vsevolod.